# In JRuby, how do I determine what causes java.lang.ThreadDeath?

Tags: ruby, debugging, jruby

While running unit tests for some code that interacts with temporary files in JRuby, I sometimes get the following:

```
Exception: java.lang.ThreadDeath thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-6395"
```

It doesn't seem to cause any problems, but what's going on, and how can I determine where it's occurring? I tried turning on `-d`, but that didn't give me a stack trace for the exception.

Comment: Don't know the answer, but the thread that died was "Thread-6395".  I think threads are numbered sequentially from 0 or 1, so this is a high number.  Is something creating more threads than it should?  Can you find out how many threads are running at any given time and make sure it's within a reasonable range for your system?

Comment: If you have any "user-space" workaround I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FWIW: This could be related to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-7074 .

I'm seeing this Thread-Death output occasionally with a JRuby programm that doesn't use backticks, but calls system.

Comment: If you have any "user-space" workaround (either ruby or java) I'd be really grateful if you could share. Can I just catch the ThreadDeath around the shell call?